# Why laravel project is throwing an error on the server like There is no existing directory at "/home/....... and its not buildable: Permission denied?

Tags: php, laravel, server

I just hosted my laravel application on the server but when I am hitting my domain I am getting the error like:

There is no existing directory at "/home/cybuzz/public_html/myproj/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied.

I have cleared the cache, given the 777 permission to the storage folder as well but the issue persists the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up file permissions for Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel)

Comment: Related: [Reason to not use chmod -R 777 on internal server for project source code?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/192197/reason-to-not-use-chmod-r-777-on-internal-server-for-project-source-code)

Answer (score -1):

Give permission to write for this directory-

If you dont have much idea about permissions, The simplest solution is

Run this command-

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/cybuzz/public_html/myproj/storage/
```

Comment: my dear, I have idea how to give permission

Comment: & I have run this as well: sudo chmod -R 777 /home/cybuzz/public_html/myproj/storage/

Comment: You can try by giving same permission to the projects root directory

Comment: @AJ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58406784/why-laravel-project-is-throwing-an-error-on-the-server-like-there-is-no-existing#comment103158213_58406960 **Never do this**.  A recursive 777 to the root directory?  As the linked duplicate says, that's a bad idea and an opening for hackers.

Comment: This why I asked if you have idea you can set accordingly. else try with 777.

Comment: @SunilChhimpa "If you don't know what you're doing use 777" is bad advice.